# How to obtain the query order output when we use grep?

Tags: linux, grep, output

I have 2 files
file1.txt

```
1
3
5
2
```

File2.txt

```
1 aaa
2 bbb
3 ccc
4 aaa
5 bbb
```

Desired output:

```
1 aaa
3 ccc
5 bbb
2 bbb
```

Command used : `cat File1.txt |grep -wf- File2.txt` but the output was:

```
1 aaa
2 bbb
3 ccc
5 bbb
```

Is it a way to return the output in the query order? 
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Important Edit**

On second thought, do not use grep with redirection as it's incredibly slow. Use awk to read the original patterns to get the order back.

**Use this instead**

```
grep -f patterns searchdata | awk 'NR==FNR { line[$1] = $0; next } $1 in line { print line[$1] }' - patterns > matched
```

---

**Benchmark**

```
#!/bin/bash
paste <(shuf -i 1-10000) <(crunch 4 4 2>/dev/null | shuf -n 10000) > searchdata
shuf -i 1-10000 > patterns

printf 'Testing awk:'
time grep -f patterns searchdata | awk 'NR==FNR { line[$1] = $0; next } $1 in line { print line[$1] }' - patterns > matched
wc -l matched

cat /dev/null > matched

printf '\nTesting grep with redirection:'
time {
    while read -r pat; do
        grep -w "$pat" searchdata >> matched
    done < patterns
}
wc -l matched
```

**Output**

```
Testing awk:
real    0m0.022s
user    0m0.017s
sys 0m0.010s
10000 matched

Testing grep with redirection:
real    0m36.370s
user    0m28.761s
sys 0m7.909s
10000 matched
```

---

**Original**

To preserve the query order, read the file line-by-line:

```
while read -r pat; do grep -w "$pat" file2.txt; done < file1.txt
```

I don't think grep has an option to support this, but this solution will be slower if you have large files to read from.

Comment: works perfectly!!!! I was struggling to figure it how its works. Indeed grep manual didn't mention something about that or having any option for this purpose.

Comment: I did some benchmarking and it was even slower than I thought. Updated version is much faster.